# Where to put the business logic in a magento module for an email form?

Tags: forms, magento, module, block, business-logic

I'm new to magento and I'm trying to create a module for an email form.

In classic MVC I would send the request to the Controller, but in Magento a controller is only responsible for one URL. So when I want to put my email form on the productpage I cant use the controller, is that right?

I inlcude my block element via layout xml in the productpage. So I have to validate my form und send the email in the class of my block element? Or would I have to write one or more helpers for that?

What is the magento way?

Thanks a lot. Sorry if my question is lame, but I'm a beginner and I want to learn the right way and I have seen so much tutorials with the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just while submitting the form give action to controller like:

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl()?>bpartner/index/mailbpartner
```

bpartner your module name 
Index your controller name 
mailbpartner your function in INDEX NAMED CONTROLLER FILE.

Get all details through POST and send mail like below + redirect with success

```
$to = "abc@abc.com";
                $dt = date('d-m-Y');
                $subject = "Become A Partner Details on date $dt";
                $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
                $mail->setBodyHtml($message)
                    ->setFrom($data['email'], $data['firstname'])
                    ->addTo($to, 'Site Admin')
                    ->setSubject($subject);
                try {
                    $mail->send();
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Mail sent successfully. We will contact you shortly');
                }
                catch(Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email.');
                }
        $this->_redirect('bpartner');
```

Some above data are POST DATA which is self understandable

Comment: Thanks. And then I can redirect with $this->_redirect to the product view :) That's great.